# 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container;For both properties-based access both setter and getter should be present

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm new to Spring boot. 
I try to implement the login and registration function using Spring Security and Hibernate.

First, I use Hibernate to generate the persistence mapping Entity Class from the database. And I need to implement UserDetails interface in the UserEntity class, but the problem happened.

I can't implement the methods in UserDetails.

Error occurs when I try to implement getAuthorities.
Here is the error information.

'Basic' attribute type should not be a container.
Inspection info: This inspection checks for the following JPA specification errors:

- Attribute types checking(collection,entity,embeddable,etc.)

For property-based access both setter and getter should be present
Inspection info:This inspection checks for the following JPA specification errors:

- More than one attribute configured for method/field
- Attribute cannot be used in Embeddable object(JPA 1.0)
- Persistent attribute metadata should be specified on field or property getter
- For property-based access both setter and getter should be present

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "demo", catalog = "")
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String nickname;
    private String phone;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){
        String[] authorities=role.split(",");
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorityList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String string:authorities)
            authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(string));
        return authorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 16)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 32)
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "nickname", nullable = true, length = 32)
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = 11)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(username, that.username) &&
                Objects.equals(password, that.password) &&
                Objects.equals(nickname, that.nickname) &&
                Objects.equals(phone, that.phone);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username, password, nickname, phone);
    }
}
```

And I have created a totally the same class as the UserEntity, with implementing UserDetails, and the problem disappeared. Maybe that's a little stupid but I've tried many times. I can't solve it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `@OneToMany` or `@Transient` instead of `@Basic` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA when one object is referencing another object or groups of objects, the relations between the two should be specified. For example:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
  // you should tell the JPA how to treat this collection
  Set<Child> children
}
```

As @Zon stated, you can skip saving it (@Transient) or save the child as another entity and defined the relations between the two (@oneToMany) or you and ignore it (@transient) or save it in Binay format as a blob (@Lob).